# tkSnack: how to play a second sound when first one is ended

Tags: python

I would love my script to play a second sound when the first one is ended. From [tkSnack documentation](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/man/snack2.2/python-man.html):

```
play ( )
Plays the sound. All options are ignored if play() is used to resume a paused play options. 
If a play() command is issued while another one is in progress,
the latter one is queued up and starts to play as soon as possible.
```

So, I thought that calling the play method on the sound object while a song was being played would result in the second song to be started when this one's finished.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to happen. In fact, as I call the `read` method on the sound object, in order to load the audio file, the player stops to play.

How should I load the audio?

I've also tried to use two different sound object, but this results in an overlapping playing.

So far, the only solution I've found is to use the `blocking` option for the `play` method. And add it in a loop:

```
for song in songList:
    SoundObject.read(song)
    SoundObject.play(blocking=True)
```

This is however far from a good solution, since it blocks the whole application, even if I start it in a daemon thread.

Here is a sample code:

```
import Tkinter, tkSnack, time
win = Tkinter.Tk()
tkSnack.initializeSnack(win)

snd = tkSnack.Sound()

def play1():
    snd.read('/home/francesco/Musica/Andrea Bocelli - Ave Maria.mp3')
    snd.play()

def play2():
    snd.read('/home/francesco/Musica/Andrea Bocelli - La voce del silenzio.mp3')
    snd.play()


b1 = Tkinter.Button(win, text="play1", command = play1)
b2 = Tkinter.Button(win, text="play2", command = play2)

b1.pack()
b2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

I would love that clicking `play2` it will "append" the soundtrack to the current one and start it as soon as the first one is ended.

Comment: it is always helpful to attach your code, not describe what your code does.

Comment: @Puciek, Added an example code.